# User input isn't being recognized, but program works if number initially set

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe, scanf

Ive been on this problem for a good while. Ill print out the double "generate" and it clearly is the number imputed by the user, but for some reason it just doesn't act the same way. This is on Unix btw.

```
double generate;
int child1, child2, retval, first, second, next, c;
//generate = 10;
first = 1;
second = 1;

retval = pipe (pfd);

if (retval != 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed\n");
    exit(0);
}

printf("Enter the number of Fibinachi numbers you'd like to generate: \n");
scanf("%d", &generate);
//printf("%d\n", generate);

child1 = fork();

if(child1 == 0)
{
    child2 = fork();

    if(child2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Im the child child \n");
        for ( c = 0; c < generate; c++ )
        {
            if ( c <= 1 )
                next = 1;
            else
            {
                next = first + second;
                first = second;
                second = next;
            }
            write (pfd[WRITE_END], &next, sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Im the child \n");
        FILE * Output;
        Output = fopen("data.txt", "w+");

        for ( c = 0; c < generate; c++ )
        {
            read(pfd[READ_END], &next, sizeof(int));
            fprintf(Output, "%d\n", next);

            printf("%d\n", next);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Hey, I am the Parent.\n");

}

exit(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `%lf` for reading double type variables.

`double generate;`

`scanf("%d", &generate);` --> `scanf("%lf", &generate);`

If the variable is initialized like `generate = 10;` then it considers as `generate = 10.0;` and works fine.

Comment: Im so happy, but at the same time I'm so frustrated it was such an easy fix.

Comment: Im waiting 4 more min cause it says I cant accept it as an answer till then